# Trouble accessing variables from different Java classes

Tags: java, class, variables, netbeans

I am trying to figure out how to get a variable from the LinearEquation class to my Main class. I have been trying to replicate the results from my instructor's notes, but it hasn't been working. I have seen examples close to what my instructor did, but mine still doesn't want to work.

Right now my goal is simple, I just want to declare `Double a = 1` in the Linear Equation class and return it to the Main class and output it there.

[Main Class](http://pastebin.com/vvbMcZ20)

[LinearEquation Class](http://pastebin.com/STauT2m6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple problems.

1. (as mentioned by @KishoreKumarKorada) is that your LinearEquation constructor is expecting multiple arguments

   `LinearEquation le = new LinearEquation(1,2,3,4,5,6);`
2. when you call a method you need to include the parentheses

   `System.out.print(le.getA());`
3. your `getA` method should refer to `this.a` rather than simply `a`

   `public double getA() {
       this.a = 1;
       return this.a;
   }`

Answer (score 1):

Double or double ? the first one is the Wrapper class and the other one is primitive type. And I notice that you don't have setter methods in your LinearEquation class. It's better that you have setter methods since your declare your class variables as private. Once you declare

```
public void setA(double a)
{
  this.a = a;
}
```

Then, you can pass value 1 to parameter in le.setA(1) in main method as following:

```
le.setA(1);
```

Then you can return the value 1 in your main method as following:

```
le.getA();
```

Otherwise, you have a constructor with 6 parameters in the LinearEquation Class. So, you can assign the values when create an object le:

```
LinearEquation le = new LinearEquation(1,2,3,4,5,6);
System.out.println(le.getA());
```

Also,you wrote le.getA without parentheses, I don't think it works!

Comment: double*

I am following an example out of the book, and it doesn't mention setters. Only getters. But I am not sure if I should add setters or not. It also mentions variables a-f are private.

The numbers (1-6), do they get anything assigned anything to them? 
for instance, does "double a = 1" "double b = 2" and so on?

Comment: I don't really sure what you mean ,but if you want double a =1, you have to assign value 1 to your field double a in main as following setA(1); and the System.out.println(getA()); is to return the value 1 to the screen. Otherwise, in main, you create a new object LinearEquation with parameter and assign values to it since you have constructor with 6 parameters in LinearEquation class and you call the getA(), getB(), etc.. method in main. http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/encapsulation-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

In your LinearEquation class you don't have default constructor, So you are not allowed to invoke constructor without passing parameters. If you pass parameters, your problem will be solved :)

```
public class Main { 
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      LinearEquation le = new LinearEquation(here pass parameters to  
                                                  initialize values);

      System.out.print(le.getA());

    }   
}
```

Comment: OH, my notes only showed one parameter, so I was thinking I only needed one parameter instead of six. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Main` class to this.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinearEquation le = new LinearEquation(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
        System.out.println(le.getA());
    }
}
```

On execution, this is the output:

```
1.0
```

**Why you need to do this?**

Because, in `LinearEquation`, there is only one constructor and it takes 6 parameters of data type `double`.

You **have to** pass those parameters.

**OR**

If you don't want to pass any parameters, then add a default constructor to `LinearEquation`